# How to filter value by exact date in dax?

Tags: powerbi, dax, ssas

I have been struggling with this for a while. I want to write something like this in dax.
So essentially I want to get value (used as a multiplier) if date is earlier than 2020-02-25.

```
var multiplier = IF ( 'D_Date'[date] > Date(2020; 2; 25); 7,5; 7,6)
return DIVIDE (
    CALCULATE ( [Paid hours (h)]; 'D_Company'[CompanyKey] <> 4 );
    CALCULATE ( SUM ( 'D_Date'[workDayFlag] ) * multiplier ) * 1;
    0
)
```

Measure Paid hours (h) has relation to the date table. The if statement doesn't work (cannot find name 'date', which exists in powerbi/SSAS and in database), but I haven't figured out any other solution.

I feel like this should be an easy task and I am suprised that my if statement doesn't work.

Comment: Try to use MAX('D_Date'[date]) instead of 'D_Date'[date]

Answer (score 0):

Since its a measure you cant directly use date column in a if statement by this way.
Try below code.

```
var multiplier = IF ( Max('D_Date'[date]) > Date(2020; 2; 25); 7,5; 7,6)
```

Comment: But that doesn't work if I aggregate based on person who has paid hours e.g 20.2.2020 and in 28.2.2020. Therefore I am always using 7,5 multiplier. I am beginning to feel like I cannot implement this feature since I don't want to make calculated columns for this.

Comment: If you can provide some sample data and also the information about, what you are getting right now and what is the expected output so it would be more helpful for us to help you.